# Como recolectar todas la etiquetas de imagenes de una pagina html en RUBY

Tags: html, ruby

Mi programa recolecta todas las direcciones de re direccionamiento pero no he podido hacer lo mismo con las etiquetas de imágenes

```
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'net/http'

    pagina  = Net::HTTP.get(ARGV[0],ARGV[1])
    enlaces = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//a[@href]').map { |link| link['href'] }
    imagenes = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//img/src').map { |link| link['src'] }
    puts "Los enlaces son: "
    puts enlaces
    puts "Las imagenes son: "
    puts imagenes
```

Comment: No he usado Ruby en mucho tiempo, pero si la página que procesas es HTML normal, entonces el problema parecería ser que estás intentando leer la etiqueta `src` dentro de la etiqueta `img`, cuando lo que quieres leer es el atributo `src` de la etiqueta `img` (algo como lo que haces con los `href` de las etiquetas `a`, en plan  `//img[@src]`). Prueba eso a ver si funciona.

Comment: Amigo, eres el mejor! funciona perfecto

Comment: Ok. Lo pongo como respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la página que procesas es HTML normal, entonces el problema es que estás intentando leer la etiqueta `src` dentro de la etiqueta `img`, cuando lo que quieres leer es el atributo `src` de la etiqueta `img` (algo como lo que haces con los `href` de las etiquetas `a`).

Entonces sólo tendrías que cambiar a `//img[@src]` en esta línea de código:

```
imagenes = Nokogiri::HTML(pagina).xpath('//img[@src]').map { |link| link['src'] }
```